# Can't receive data in python node

Tags: ros, ros2, rclpy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I don't know how to debug this:
I took the python demo listener and changed it to subscribe to odometry.
But when I subscribe to my running cpp node which publishes odom, I don't receive any data ...
If I use a cmd publisher like `ros2 topic pub /odom nav_msgs/msg/Odometry`, listener receives data..
Also if I use my own cpp odom publisher and the cmd line publisher at the same time, I only receive data from cmd publisher...

But echo gives me data from both publishers...

Namespace is correct, topic is correct.

I am running on empty now ...

```
from std_msgs.msg import String
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry

class Listener(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('odom_listener')
        self.sub = self.create_subscription(Odometry, 'odom', self.chatter_callback, 10)

    def chatter_callback(self, msg):
        self.get_logger().info('I heard odom')


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)

    node = Listener()
    rclpy.spin(node)

    node.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As requested cpp publisher:

```
   odomPub = this->create_publisher<Odom>( "odom", rclcpp::SensorDataQoS() );
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/332207/can%27t-receive-data-in-python-node/) by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 496 on 2019-09-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-09-03**:
My guess would be this has something to do with the namespace of the topic you're using. Have you tried using `/odom` in your code instead of `odom`?

**Comment by [SamsAutonomy](https://answers.ros.org/users/45348/samsautonomy/) on 2019-09-03**:
@madmax What is the output of your CPP node? Add a code snippet of the CPP node publisher, it would be helpful.

**Comment by [SamsAutonomy](https://answers.ros.org/users/45348/samsautonomy/) on 2019-09-03**:
@madmax More questions :) What does `ros2 topic list` return? With both publishers running.

Also, how do you know which publisher is reaching your callback when you: **Also if I use my own cpp odom publisher and the cmd line publisher at the same time, I only receive data from cmd publisher...**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the QoS settings on the publisher and subscriber are incompatible.
Change the QoS settings on either the publisher or the listener to match.
See the page [About Quality of Service Settings](https://index.ros.org//doc/ros2/Concepts/About-Quality-of-Service-Settings/) for more info.

The C++ publisher is using `rclcpp::SensorDataQoS()`, which uses the   [sensor data QoS profile](https://github.com/ros2/rmw/blob/9f2e181306c66ac0f09674086a108d4657611766/rmw/include/rmw/qos_profiles.h#L25-L36).
The Python subscriber is just specifying the queue size, which means it uses [the default profile](https://github.com/ros2/rmw/blob/9f2e181306c66ac0f09674086a108d4657611766/rmw/include/rmw/qos_profiles.h#L51-L62) with the given queue size of 10.
The incompatibility comes from the `reliability` setting.
The sensor data profile specifies `best effort` while the default profile uses `reliable`.
According to the [QoS compatibilities table](https://index.ros.org//doc/ros2/Concepts/About-Quality-of-Service-Settings/#qos-compatibilities),
a subscriber requiring `reliable` will not connect to a publisher providing only `best effort` reliability.

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2019-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on 2019-09-03**:
Good hint! Coming from ros 1 where its not that strict...

**Comment by [deb0ch](https://answers.ros.org/users/43192/deb0ch/) on 2020-03-09**:
This hint helped me find the answer with (somewhat) code that solved this for me: https://index.ros.org//doc/ros2/Concepts/About-Quality-of-Service-Settings/#qos-compatibilities